# Android Image Cropped Type Circle Add Scale

Tags: java, android, android-imageview, android-image

I have a method to Cropped image to circle and work fine but need scale type to center crop or center in image but dont work if I define in XML file.

In xml value= SCALE TYPE= CENTER_CROP OR SCALE_TYPE CENTER
This is my class button:

```
public class CircleImage extends ImageView {

public CircleImage(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CircleImage(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public CircleImage(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    Drawable drawable = getDrawable();

    if (drawable == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (getWidth() == 0 || getHeight() == 0) {
        return;
    }
    Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
    Bitmap bitmap = b.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

    int w = getWidth(), h = getHeight();

    Bitmap roundBitmap = getCroppedBitmap(bitmap, w);
    canvas.drawBitmap(roundBitmap, 0, 0, null);

}

public static Bitmap getCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bmp, int radius) {
    Bitmap sbmp;

    if (bmp.getWidth() != radius || bmp.getHeight() != radius) {
        float smallest = Math.min(bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight());
        float factor = smallest / radius;
        sbmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, (int)(bmp.getWidth() / factor), (int)(bmp.getHeight() / factor), false);
    } else {
        sbmp = bmp;
    }

    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(radius, radius,
            Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final int color = 0xffa19774;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, radius, radius);

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
    paint.setDither(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#BAB399"));
    canvas.drawCircle(radius / 2 + 0.7f,
            radius / 2 + 0.7f, radius / 2 + 0.1f, paint);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(sbmp, rect, rect, paint);

    return output;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass a complete and fixed class for circle image and center scale type

```
public class CircleImage extends ImageView {

public CircleImage(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CircleImage(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public CircleImage(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    Drawable drawable = getDrawable();

    if (drawable == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (getWidth() == 0 || getHeight() == 0) {
        return;
    }
    Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
    Bitmap bitmap = b.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

    int w = getWidth(), h = getHeight();

    Bitmap bm_scale_center_crop;
    if (bitmap.getWidth() >= bitmap.getHeight()){

        bm_scale_center_crop = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                bitmap,
                bitmap.getWidth()/2 - bitmap.getHeight()/2,
                0,
                bitmap.getHeight(),
                bitmap.getHeight()
        );

    }else{

        bm_scale_center_crop = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                bitmap,
                0,
                bitmap.getHeight()/2 - bitmap.getWidth()/2,
                bitmap.getWidth(),
                bitmap.getWidth()
        );
    }
    Bitmap roundBitmap = getCroppedBitmap(bitmap, w);
    canvas.drawBitmap(roundBitmap, 0, 0, null);

}
```